# How to compare and get confidence intervals for paired proportions (correct detection rates) using McNemar's test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, confidence-interval, proportion, mcnemar-test

I want to compare the diagnostic efficiencies of two methods using overall correct classification rates (i.e., `(sensitivity+specificity)/2`, and assuming approx. equal samples for positive and negative cases), in paired samples. Several papers advocate the use of McNemar (e.g. [this](https://www.ajronline.org/doi/full/10.2214/AJR.08.1090) and [this](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0962280214541852), see also [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241787/mcnemars-test-how-to-compare-two-proportions-in-dependent-sample/241844#241844)), although some seem to find fault with this approach (e.g. [this](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00365510701666031?journalCode=iclb20)). However, these papers are very technical and mostly address sensitivity and specificity separately rather than together in a single overall accuracy rate as I want to.

Assuming that using McNemar test for the comparison is correct (but tell me if not), I would also like to get confidence intervals for the overall **accuracy (i.e., proportion) difference**. Functions for McNemar typically give *odds ratios* or similar, but that doesn't seem practical for my purpose.

Now, as far as I understand, the McNemar test boils down to a simple proportion test, and therefore I may use the confidence intervals from that proportion test. Consider the following example.

```r
repn = 6
outcomes_A = rep(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                   0), repn)
outcomes_B = rep(c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                   1), repn)
mean(outcomes_A) # proportion (of correct classifications): 
  0.6470588
mean(outcomes_B) # proportion (of correct classifications): 
  0.8235294
mydat = xtabs(~ outcomes_A + outcomes_B)
mydat

        outcomes_B
outcomes_A  0  1
        0  6 30
        1 12 54
```

Now, using `mcnemar.test(mydat)` gives the [same results](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-January/064691.html) as using `prop.test(mydat[1,2], mydat[2,1]+mydat[1,2])`, but the latter actually provides confidence intervals. However, this is not the confidence interval I want: this confidence interval is for the proportion difference between the "`P01`" and "`P10`" observations in the [conventional matrix input](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Tests_for_Two_Correlated_Proportions-McNemar_Test.pdf) (as above in `mydat`). However, I think I can correct this by adjusting the numbers using the proportion of "`P01`" and "`P10`" observations to all observations.

```r
res = prop.test(mydat[1, 2], mydat[2, 1] + mydat[1, 2])
discr = mydat[2, 1] + mydat[1, 2]
# starting from (res$estimate * discr - (1 - res$estimate) * 
                 discr) / sum(mydat)
(res$estimate * 2 - 1) * discr / sum(mydat) # difference
(res$conf.int[1] * 2 - 1) * discr / sum(mydat)  # lower CI limit
(res$conf.int[2] * 2 - 1) * discr / sum(mydat)  # upper CI limit
```

Which gives a difference of **.1764706, 95% CI [.042812, .2781084]**. Reassuringly, the calculated difference of .1764706 is identical with the actual proportion (i.e. accuracy rate) difference calculated from the original data: 0.8235294 - 0.6470588 = **0.1764706**

I also compared the outcome of this procedure of mine to a [MedCalc example](https://www.medcalc.org/manual/mcnemartest2.php), and the CI seems very close, though not the same – but I'd guess it's just because of a slightly different McNemar test variation.

```r
mydat = matrix(c(212, 256, 144, 707), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
mydat
# p1 = sum(mydat[1, ]) / sum(mydat)
# p2 = sum(mydat[, 1]) / sum(mydat)
# p1
# p2
# p2-p1
# mcnemar.test(mydat)
res = prop.test(mydat[2, 1], mydat[2, 1] + mydat[1, 2])
discr = mydat[2, 1] + mydat[1, 2]
(res$estimate * 2 - 1) * discr / sum(mydat) # difference
(res$conf.int[1] * 2 - 1) * discr / sum(mydat)  # 0.05492 vs. MedCalc's 0.0555
(res$conf.int[2] * 2 - 1) * discr / sum(mydat)  # 0.11324 vs. MedCalc's 0.1143
```

Nonetheless, I'm not sure whether all this reasoning is correct and sensible. **So my eventual question: is this an appropriate and ideal procedure for comparing overall accuracy rates and getting their confidence intervals? (And if not, what would be better?)**

(Note: I'm well aware of the possibility of comparing AUCs, but that is not what I want; AUC is again not as practical a measure as simple accuracy rate.)